# redirect WP post from one subdomain to WP page on domain subdirectory using htaccess- file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, subdirectory

I got a issue with my htaccess-file. I learned a thing or two when it comes on rewriting through the htaccess-file, but this one is really keeping me awake. Hopefully one of you can help me solve with this matter. The situation is the following.

I want to redirect some specific WP blog posts (permanently) from a subdomain to some specific pages on this WP main domain subdirectory. I'm using a WP Multi subdomain website. Here's what I mean:

`sub1.domain.com/postname`
needs to be redirected to:
`domain.com/sub1/pagename`

I can't figure out how to get this done. Here's how my WP htaccess- file that's located on the root of this subdomain normally looks like:

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

I hope someone can help me with this matter. It will truly help me. Thanks in forward!

Greets, Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following `HTTP_HOST` rule just before your *wordpress* rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^postname/?$ http://domain.com/pagename [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

---

To redirect `sub.domain.com` to `domain.com/subdir`, you would use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for your quick reply! Wow, this really seems to work; ) Could you also tell me if it's still possible to add a rule that redirects from (for example) sub1.domain.com to domain.com/subdirectory? Greets, Marc

Comment: Hi Ravi, thank you so much for the fast help! This info is really useful to my websites. Greets, Marc